# Wordpress login in error wp-admin err_too_many_redirects

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a problem with wordpress login. I am using wordpress 3.9 and suddenly I am unable to login to my admin or any account. When I type https://lifesymb.com/wp-admin/ then I am getting the following error.

```
This webpage has a redirect loop 
The webpage at https://example.com/wp-admin/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Learn more about this problem.
Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I tried by clearing my cookies, tried in another computer and tried changing the .htaaccess as below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And tried many  ways but I am unscuccessful but my site is displaying good and my site uses SSL. so could any one help me in solving this issuse.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `restoring the default .htaccess file?`

Comment: I have know to restore the .htacess file because I am using the default  .htaccess    file until this problem arises and when the problem arises then browsing in  the internet I found some suggesstion then started to test it but I failed with those suggestions also .